# qt how can I reload the resources files

Tags: qt, qfile, qtstylesheets

I'm using stylesheet for my new widget. I want to add a reload button just for designing. So I add a stylesheet.txt in Resouces/.../xxx.qrc file as the style sheet to apply for my widget. And I have a QPushButton to trigger setStyleSheet() with a QFile to open the stylesheet.txt. And I want to edit the txt outside the program with defaut editor in system. But I found that the resources files are not refreshed which means when I edit the txt, the txt doesn't reload in the program. Any idea how can I reload the file or any solution, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General suggestion: do not put resources in .qrc during debug / design. I recommend to use a `QDir::setSearchPaths` instead:

```
    void Application::setDirs()
    {
#ifdef QT_DEBUG
        QDir dir( QGuiApplication::applicationDirPath() );
        dir.cd( "C:/DotaClient" );
        QDir::setSearchPaths( "qml", QStringList( dir.absolutePath() ) );
#else
        QDir::setSearchPaths( "qml", QStringList( ":/DotaClient/" ) );
#endif
    }
```

Access:

```
m_mainView->setSource( QUrl( "qml:Root/Root.qml" ) );
```

Or something like `background-image:url(images:Root/root_bg.png);` in QSS.

In this case, file `Root.qml` will be looked in `C:/DotaClient/Root/Root.qml` in debug build (with possibility of dynamic reloading), and in `:/DotaClient/Root/Root.qml` (in resources) in release build.

Comment: Ty. works fine :) btw, I saw rcc solution for dynamic resource file. Is it good as well?

Comment: Yes. It is possible to create command file (cmd / bat / sh) to run script for rebuilding resources. But you must reload them manually throught `QResource` class. See documantation: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/rcc.html

Answer (score 2):

Resources are embedded into the binaries upon compilation. If you edit one of the resource files you'll have to rebuild the application. So, if you want dynamically change styles  without recompiling/restarting, just load style-sheet from an external file, but not from resources.

Answer (score 2):

From the Qt Doc:

*"The Qt resource system is a platform-independent mechanism for storing binary files in the application's executable. This is useful if your application always needs a certain set of files (icons, translation files, etc.) and you don't want to run the risk of losing the files."*

The resources are stored in the binaries, you can only update them if you rebuild your application. Use a other file to load your stylesheet.

Comment: It is possible to compile resources to external file in RCC format. So it is not necessary to recompile application binaries.